# Rounding duration or period to full minutes with lubridate

Tags: r, date, time, lubridate

Does anybody have a neater way of rounding lubridate period and duration objects to minutes instead of seconds.

For example, I have the following pipe of code:

```
seconds(x = 3600115) %>% as.duration() %>%  as.period()
```

This results in: `41d 16H 1M 55S`. I would like to round it so it becomes: `41d 16H 2M 0S`.

Is anybody aware of a better way than:

```
(seconds(x = 3600115) / 60) %>% as.numeric() %>% round() %>% dminutes() %>% as.period()
```

This results in: `41d 16H 2M 0S`

Answer (score 4):

A duration object is stored numerically as the number of seconds and period objects can conveniently be converted into seconds using `period_to_seconds()` so you could use a simple function for this:

```
library(lubridate)

# Create period object
p <- seconds_to_period(3600115)

# Create duration object
d <- as.duration(p)

minround <- function(x) {
  stopifnot(is.period(x) || is.duration(x))
  if (is.duration(x))
    round(x / 60) * 60
  else
    seconds_to_period(round(period_to_seconds(x) / 60) * 60)
}

minround(p)
# [1] "41d 16H 2M 0S"

minround(d)
# [1] "3600120s (~5.95 weeks)"
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R option :

```
as.POSIXct(3600115 - 86400, origin = '1970-01-01', tz = 'UTC') %>%
  round('mins') %>%
  format('%jd %HH %MM 0S')

#[1] "041d 16H 02M 0S"
```

Few things to note -

- Used pipe for readability.
- Output is a string object and not period object.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I like the solution at the end better as it a period object.

Comment: @Jochem  You can add `%>% as.period()` to above answer to get output as a period object in the end.